# Swagger page being redirected from https to http

Tags: asp.net-web-api, https, swagger, swashbuckle

AWS Elastic Load Balancer listening through HTTPS (443) using SSL and redirecting requests to EC2 instances through HTTP (80), with IIS hosting a .net webapi application, using swashbuckle to describe the API methods.

Home page of the API (https://example.com) has a link to Swagger documentation which can bee read as https://example.com/swagger/ui/index.html when you hove over on the link.

- If I click on the link it redirects the request on the browser to http://example.com/swagger/ui/index.html which displays a Page Not Found error
- but if I type directly in the browser URL https://example.com/swagger/ui/index.html then it loads Swagger page, but then, when expanding the methods an click on "Try it out", the Request URL starts with  "http" again.

This configuration is only for Stage and Production environments. Lower environments don't use the load balancer and just use http.

Any ideas on how to stop https being redirected to http? And how make swagger to display Request URLs using https?

Thank you

EDIT:
I'm using a custom index.html file

Comment: What's the issue with using a different swagger file for a different environnement? I suppose the URLs are different in Production compared to Dev environnement, no?

Comment: URLs are different in each environment. Is there a solution not involving a different file per environment?

Comment: i have a similar problem. Any updates?

Answer (score 1):

Seems is a known issue for Swashbuckle. Quote:

"*By default, the service root url is inferred from the request used to access the docs. However, there may be situations (e.g. proxy and load-balanced environments) where this does not resolve correctly. You can workaround this by providing your own code to determine the root URL.*"

What I did was provide the root url and/or scheme to use based on the environment

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                   .EnableSwagger(c =>
                    {
                       ... 
                       c.RootUrl(req => GetRootUrlFromAppConfig(req));
                       ... 
                       c.Schemes(GetEnvironmentScheme());
                       ...
                    })
                    .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
                    {
                       ...
                    });
```

where

```
    public static string[] GetEnvironmentScheme()
    {
        ...
    }

    public static string GetRootUrlFromAppConfig(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
       ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would probably do it is having a main file, and generating during the build of your application a different swagger file based on the environnement parameters for schemes and hosts.

That way, you have to manage only one swagger file accross your environments, and you only have to manage a few extra environnement properties, host and schemes (if you don't already have them)

Since I don't know about swashbuckle, I cannot answer for sure at your first question (the redirect)